# Minimize and maximize buttons don't work but maximizing/minimizing by alt+space menu works

Tags: qt

I have a window as shown below, the max/min buttons don't work but I can use the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> menu to max/min/resize the window:

[image: max/min/resize issue]

The window is a `QMainWindow`:

```
// MainWindow constructor
MainWindow::MainWindow(): QMainWindow(0) {
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result;
    try {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        result = a.exec();
    }
    catch (...) {
        result = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm on openSUSE Leap 15 with Gnome 3:

```
> gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.26.2
```

---

I'm using `Qt 5.11`

---

I'm not setting any size policy for `MainWindow`. Did anybody run into this issue before?

Comment: Size policy does not affect these buttons at all; It only affects how sibling widgets share their parent layout's size. Do these buttons work as expected on other platforms? Are you sure you are not setting any [windowFlags](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)? see also [`setWindowFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop)...

Comment: @Mike Thanks, I'm going to check `windowFlags`

Comment: @Mike I checked, I'm not using `windowFlags`. Now, I'm going to test the app on other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested the app with Gnome on **Wayland** and Gnome on **Xorg**. My conclusion is that this issue happens when Gnome on **Wayland** is used. When using Gnome on **Xorg**, there is no such issue.

As shown in the following screen-shot, when app is running with Gnome on **Xorg** the min/max/close/resize all look and work as expected:

[image]